# Passing an array in django urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-views

Can we pass an array to a django url

```
   <script>
     function save()
     {
       window.location = "/display/xlsdisplay/" + objarr ;   
     }

    var objarr = new Array();

    </script>
```

Urls.py

```
         (r'^xlsdisplay/(?P<qid>\d+)$', 'xlsdisplay'),
```

There is an error saying

```
             http://192.168.1.11/display/xlsdisplay/334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The regular expression used in your URL will only match a sequence of digits. The comma will require a different expression.
2. I don't know your specific need but you ought to look at [naming](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) URLs rather than hard cording them.

Comment: Re 2. if the JS is not rendered as part of a django template, using a reverse lookup of a named URL won't work, of course.

Comment: @stevejalim: you are correct. I saw the inline `<script>` tags and figured that the JS might be included in the template.